# Regex expression for accepsts only ()+ and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to use with Javascript .test
like using this examples

```
+999904321493214032
and
(+999)432143214
and
432143124321
```

Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: How about `/^[+()\d]+$/`

Comment: it works, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tightest I can think of is:

```
^(?:\(\+\d+\)|\+)?\d+$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/E7P3Z7FmJo) showing matching your examples and not matching input with the correct characters but that are malformed (eg imbalanced brackets).